# Jquery .on() Scroll not functioning on dynamic div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have tried about every other "solution" that I have found on SO and on other parts of the web and still cannot get this to work.

I have a dynamically created div with `position: fixed; overflow-y: auto`, the div is created when a user clicks a certain link. This is the function I'm using to try and execute some code whenever that dynamically created div is scrolled.

```
        $("#scroller").on("scroll",function() {
           console.log("scrolled..");
        });
```

`#scroller` is the ID of the dynamically created `div`.

The thing is, this function **does not work** when the page is loaded, but it **does work** when the function is pasted into the developer console in Google Chrome.

I have tried everything from using a regular `scroll()` function to changing the `on()` function to the following:

```
    $("#scroller-container").on("scroll","#scroller",function() {
       console.log("scrolled..");
    });
```

Yet it still does not work.

How can I get this to work?

**EDIT: All the code is within a `jQuery(window).load(function ()...` function**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding scroll event after the element is appended on the DOM, like this:

```js
$("body").on("DIVscroll", "#scroller", function(){
  console.log("Scrolled...");
});

$("#btn").on("click", function(){
  $("body").append('<div id="scroller">I have a dynamically created div with position: fixed; overflow-y: auto, the div is created when a user clicks a certain link. This is the function Im using to try and execute some code whenever that dynamically created div is scrolled.</div>');
  ScrollEventListener($("#scroller"));
});

function ScrollEventListener(el){
  el.on("scroll", function(){
    el.trigger("DIVscroll");
  });
}
```

```css
body{
  font-size: 17px;
}
 
#scroller{
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Append div"/>
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer as correct because it fully works and led me to fixing the problem! Thanks!